# Two nvarchar columns into one datetime. MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, varchar

I have two columns:

```
 date(nvarchar) - it looks like '2015-04-15 00:00:00.000' 
 time(nvarchar) - looks like '1899-12-30 11:20:25.000'
```

I need to merge that into one column(datetime). How I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't store date/time values as characters.  But, you can convert them and add them:

```
select cast(datechar as datetime) + cast(right(timechar, 12) as time)
```

I just realized.  I don't recall if the default date/time formats understand the fractional seconds.  The following is safer:

```
select (convert(datetime, datechar, 121) +
        convert(time, convert(datetime, timechar, 121))
       ) as datetimeval
```

Comment: Addition works for different datatpes? (datetime and time)

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . I'm surprised the documentation is not better, but I did find:  "The plus (+) and minus (-) operators can also be used to perform arithmetic operations on datetime and smalldatetime values."  The conversion to time is to ensure that there is only a `time` component; I guess SQL Server converts it back to a `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

After you have added the 3rd column (`[FullDate]`) for example, you can use the below code:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET [FullDate] = DATEADD(SECOND, SECOND(TIME), DATEADD(MINUTE, MINUTE(TIME), DATEADD(HOUR, HOUR(TIME), DATE)))
```

Alternatively, you can do as @GordonLinoff mentioned, but make sure you cast the `time` part to `datetime`. So, something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET [FullDate] = CAST([date] as DATETIME) + CAST([time] AS DATETIME)
```